# Rails returning pointer when nesting comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving a pointer when I try to return a nested comment, for example:

```
def index
  comments = Comment.limit(2)
  newcomments = []
  newcomments << comments[0]
  newcomments[0].children << comments[1]
  render json: {comments:newcomments}
end
```

what I expect I would get back is:

```
comments:{
   'title':'title'
   'body':'body',
   'children':[{
              'title':'title',
              'body':'body,
              'children':[]
   }]
}
```

but instead get back:

```
 comments:{
       'title':'title'
       'body':'body',
       'children':[#<Comment:0x007fd243320718>:Object]
}
```

I'm new to rails and have been trying to get this for the past couple of days, any advice would be extremely appreciated.

Is this related to this: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/835?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
def index
  comments = Comment.limit(2)
  newcomments = []
  newcomments << comments[0]
  newcomments[0].children << comments[1].as_json
  render json: {comments:newcomments}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Overall, this question was poorly asked, but yes, the above answer is technically correct. However, the more correct answer to my struggle was that I needed to do

```
.as_json.merge!(:children=>[]).
```